# How to ensure that user & pass is correct in curl using bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl, stdout

I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ];then
   echo "Usage: ./script <input-file>"
   exit 1
fi

while read user pass; do
curl -iL --data-urlencode  user="$user" --data-urlencode password="$pass" http://foo.com/signin 1>/dev/null 2>&1
   if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
      echo "ok"
   elif [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "failed"
   fi
done < $1
```

**question:**

Whenever I run with even wrong user & pass the result is `ok` for me...

How can I be sure that my parameters are correct or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because you are getting output from your curl command. Typing that command with random user/pass gets this:

```
$ curl -iL --data-urlencode  user=BLAHBLAH --data-urlencode password=BLAH http://foo.com/signin 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.0.5
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2014 05:53:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.foo.com/signin
. . .
. . .
<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/500.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>We're sorry, but something went wrong.</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hence,

```
$ echo $?
0
```

But modify the URL to garbage:

```
$ curl -iL --data-urlencode  user=BLAHBLAH --data-urlencode password=BLAH http://foof.com/signin 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foof.com
$ echo $?
6
```

Comment: Ok, but how is it possible with bash written in myself? because of exercising a bruteforce...Thanks

Comment: @MortezaLSC It would be difficult using just the `$?`. You’ll probably have to evaluate the text returned by `curl` command.

Comment: I did it with a wrong user pass and result was `0` again

Comment: Like I said, since curl is returning garbage instead of error, `$?` will not capture it. You will have to parse the return of curl to evaluate if it is a success or failure.

Comment: So I think I should use `python` to parse the out put, OR completely switch to python, right?

Comment: Yes, instead of redirecting the STDOUT to /dev/null, redirect tj to a file and then parse the file using any language to determine if it is success or failed log in.

Answer (score 1):

Even when the login fails, the HTTP server will still return a page with an error message. As `curl` is able to retrieve this page it will finish successfully.

In order to get `curl` to fail on server errors, you need the `--fail` parameter. Although this may not be fail-safe according to the curl man page, it is worth a try.

If `--fail` does not work, you could parse the header in the output of your curl request or have a look at the `--write-out` parameter.

Comment: How can be sure which one is true? Thank you

Comment: The only way to be sure is to try it with the HTTP server in question. Responses to failed (and also successful) login attempts can differ quite a bit.